# Обрезать строку

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, требуеться помощь, как обрезать title пробывал методами, но моих навыков малова-то.

```
        $onpage = 6; // записей на страницу
        $table = "ak_category"; // из какой таблицы
        $page = page(); // определяем страницу
        $result = sql_query($onpage, $page, $table); // sql - запрос
        $row = array();
        for ($i=0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) { 
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
            printf("
            <a href='?option=products&cat=%s' class='nam'>
                <div class='main_block'>
                <img src='%s' />
                <div class='name'>%s</div>
                </div>
                </a>
            ",$row['id'],$row['img'],$row['title']);
        }
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: Вы не могли бы по-русски написать что вы хотите ? не умничая особо. в терминологии вы всё равно ничего не понимаете. Что вот например значит "обрезать title" ? какими методами вы пробовали ? Почитайте крайне полезное для вас сочинение http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html

Comment: Обрезать допустим до 15 символов вывод $row['title']

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php

Comment: Прочитайте первое сообщение, может тогда умный человек кинет пример?

Comment: Не надо называть других людей глупыми (даже косвенно) только из-за того, что вы ленитесь прочитать описание функции. По вышеуказанной ссылке все расписано простым и доступным языком. И по сути, раз вы отказываетесь прочитать описание функции, вам требуется не помощь, а готовое решение. Фу таким быть.

Comment: я пробывал данный метод, но пример был показан не правильный... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$onpage = 6; // записей на страницу
$table = "ak_category"; // из какой таблицы
$page = page(); // определяем страницу
$result = sql_query($onpage, $page, $table); // sql - запрос
$row = array();
for ($i=0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) { 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
    printf("
    <a href='?option=products&cat=%s' class='nam'>
        <div class='main_block'>
        <img src='%s' />
        <div class='name'>%s</div>
        </div>
        </a>
    ",$row['id'],$row['img'],substr($row['title'],0,15)); //Изменения в этой строке
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, пробывал, но на примере точки были... Тока бывает заканчиваеться на знак вопроса в ромбе )

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
function truncate($string, $length=15, $encoding='UTF-8') {
     if (mb_strlen($string, $encoding) > $length - 3)
         return mb_substr($string, 0, $length, $encoding).'...';
     return $string;
}
```

2.

```
<a href="?option=products&cat=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="nam">
    <img src="<?php echo $row['img']; ?>" />
    <div class="name"><?php echo truncate($row['title']); ?></div>
</a>
```

3.
[Как пиштся пробовал или пробывал и почему?](http://otvet.mail.ru/question/29277055)

4.
[Правописание "-тся" и "-ться" в глаголах](http://tsya.ru/)